# Build dependent project with Maven

Tags: maven

I have a project A of type war (or ejb) which has a dependency on some other war project B of mine. 
Is it possible to build project B before including it as a dependency to the project A with `mvn package`? 
**Note:** I wouldn't like to change the packaging types of my projects and wouldn't like to change the parent-child relationship between my projects.

Comment: A dependency on a war project usually does not make sense...but without the pom files and a more detailed explanation what you like to do it's impossible to help..

Comment: I would like to use this .war dependency to build my test archive using ShrinkWrap.

Comment: If you have a dependency of type war in your module you need to add `<type>war</type>` otherwise it's assumed you are using a jar file...